# How to find max number from an array, but from selected elements only in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my array from which I want to find max.

```
number = {"abc": [43,4,34,34,6,444], "dsfsd":[324,324,32,43,34,2] };
console.log((Math.max(...number[abc]));
```

Here the output is 444, and it's working fine. But now, I want to select max from selected indexs. I am storing those indexes in this array.

`available = [0,2,3];`

Now, index 0,2,3 of `number[abc]` are 43,34, 6

And I want 43 to be displayed, because it is the max from selected indexes.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map the indicies to the values, and then call `Math.max` on those values:

```js
const number = {"abc": [43,4,34,34,6,444], "dsfsd":[324,324,32,43,34,2] };
const available = [0,2,3];
const availableValues = available.map(i => number.abc[i]);
console.log(Math.max(...availableValues));
```

Comment: Why are you using const?

Comment: `const` is the keyword to use by default when declaring variables; `var` has unintuitive function scope rather than block scope, and `var` gets hoisted, so it's much easier to make mistakes with it. `let` is an indicator to readers of your code that you need to *reassign* a variable; if you're not going to reassign (such as in this snippet), better to use `const`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a reusable function that will have a custom logic to check the highest number instead of using `Math.max()`. Using reusable function will help you to scale the code without duplicating the logic.

```js
var available = [0,2,3];
var number = {"abc": [43,4,34,34,6,444], "dsfsd":[324,324,32,43,34,2] };

function getHighest(available, number){
  var index = available[0];
  var highest = number[index];
  for(var i=1; i<available.length; i++){
    index = available[i];
    if(highest < number[index]){
      highest = number[index];
    }
  }
  return highest;
}
var highest = getHighest(available, number['abc']);
console.log(highest);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also achview this by filtering the `number.abc` array.

```js
const number = {"abc": [43,4,34,34,6,444], "dsfsd":[324,324,32,43,34,2] };
const available = [0,2,3];
const filtered = number.abc.filter((num, idx) => available.includes(idx));
console.log(Math.max(...filtered));
```

Comment: Why are you using const?

Comment: Short answer: Because the variables do not not change here. Long answer: I actually use `const` whereever possible and avoid using `var` or `let` whereever possible. It makes writing code much easier for me to know that some variable assignements won't be changed anywhere else in the codebase. And (at least it feels like as) there is more room for runtime optimizations of my code when the runtime *knows* there will be no change to some variables.